# Why do i get a Key Error in my Nested Dict

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Overwiew of the income of all years with the months in it to see how the income changed after i added them.

```
jahre = 3
monate = 12
mydict = {}
a = 1
b = 1
aa = 00
uu = 0
for oo in range(jahre):
        mydict[str(a)] = str(uu)
        for wu in range(monate):
               mydict[jahre][str(b)] = {}
               b = b + 1
        a = a + 1
print(mydict)
```

What i get as Output is :

```
mydict[jahre][str(b)] = {}
KeyError: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your code, `mydict[1]` does not exist, thus the KeyError. Note that `mydict["1"]`, however, does exist as you have set it in your first for loop.

This is however not the best way to create the dictionary that you want to get, and your code won't work as such.

Here's a decomposed way to achieve what you want to do.

```
# first, let's set the variables for years and months, as you want 3 years and 12 months in each year
years = 3
months = 12

# then, let's initialise the dictionary
mydict = {}

# now comes the code to fill this dictionary

# first, we have a for loop over the years to generate the first level of the nested dictionary
# note that we use range(1, years+1) and not range(years) because range(years) iterate over 0, 1 and 2 and we want it to iterate over 1, 2 and 3
for year in range(1, years+1):
    # for each year, we want to generate a key
    # here, we set the "Year N." with the year number at the end
    # so, for each year in the loop, it will create a key whose value will be, for instance, "Year N.1"
    mydict["Year N."+str(year)] = {}
    # now let's do the same but for months
    # the same logic applies here, we iterate over each month
    for month in range(1, months+1):
        # now, we create a key for the month within the desired year
        # note that here, the variable year is still the one over which it iterates in the first loop
        # in the same way, we create each key like "Month N.11" for instance
        mydict["Year N."+str(year)]["Month N."+str(month)] = {}
```

This bit of code without the comments gives us:

```
years = 3
months = 12
mydict = {}

for year in range(1, years+1):
    mydict["Year N."+str(year)] = {}
    for month in range(1, months+1):
        mydict["Year N."+str(year)]["Month N."+str(month)] = {}
```

In the end, the nested dictionary `mydict` will look like this:

```
{'Year N.1': {'Month N.1': {},
  'Month N.2': {},
  'Month N.3': {},
  'Month N.4': {},
  'Month N.5': {},
  'Month N.6': {},
  'Month N.7': {},
  'Month N.8': {},
  'Month N.9': {},
  'Month N.10': {},
  'Month N.11': {},
  'Month N.12': {}},
 'Year N.2': {'Month N.1': {},
  'Month N.2': {},
  'Month N.3': {},
  'Month N.4': {},
  'Month N.5': {},
  'Month N.6': {},
  'Month N.7': {},
  'Month N.8': {},
  'Month N.9': {},
  'Month N.10': {},
  'Month N.11': {},
  'Month N.12': {}},
 'Year N.3': {'Month N.1': {},
  'Month N.2': {},
  'Month N.3': {},
  'Month N.4': {},
  'Month N.5': {},
  'Month N.6': {},
  'Month N.7': {},
  'Month N.8': {},
  'Month N.9': {},
  'Month N.10': {},
  'Month N.11': {},
  'Month N.12': {}}}
```

Please feel free to ask if the answer isn't clear enough. I would highly suggest you to run this code in an interpreter that lets you look at what is happening to your variables at each iteration to better understand how it works if you do not understand it from the code and the comments. You can use [OnlineGDB's interpreter](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger) and its debugging option for this.

Comment: Then this happens: `mydict[str(jahre)][str(b)] = {}
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Ok I tried to run your code and realised that it will first and foremost not work because when doing ```mydict[str(jahre)][str(b)] = {}```, it will try to do ```mydict["3"]["1"] = {}``` because the variable ```jahre``` is set to ```3``` and the variable ```b``` to ```1```,  but the problem is that you have never defined ```mydict["3"]``` in the first place (it's not in the dictionary's keys). Can you provide more details on what the dictionary that you want to create looks like?

Comment: It should look like this: `mydict = {year1: {"month1": 343, "month2" : 2432,...},
          year2: {same here}}`

Comment: I edited my answer and suggested a bit of code that might clear things out. If you understand what's going on, don't forget to mark this as an answer! :)

Comment: How did u get an Output with a new line each month tho?

Comment: How the output is formatted depends on the console of your Python interpreter! Mine does this automatically which is great, but that does not change the actual value of the nested dict!

Comment: What Interpreter do you use?

Comment: I'm using Atom as an IDE and its package Hydrogen allows to run code seamlessly inside of it! But I would definitely rather recommend using Jupyter Notebook if you've recently started Python.